# Uniquity? Uniqueness?

Tags: discussion

Just spotted a new **uniquity** tag, for words that express uniqueness. While I don't object to the idea of the tag, I'm puzzled by its name, which appears to be a rare, possibly obsolete variant of *uniqueness.* Should it be changed or syn-linked to the more common term? Or is there some reason to expect that people will use it more as currently spelled?

Comment: Argh...just say it's not a word...because it's not. Retag all to uniqueness and be done with it.

Comment: It's a uniquely silly tag.

Comment: I would read ‘uniquity’ as [ˌʌnˈɪkwɪti], i.e., as a somewhat mis-prefixed alternative form of _iniquity_, perhaps a portmanteau of _iniquity_ and _unequal_. It would not have occurred to me, if I’d just seen the tag, that it actually referred to uniqueness.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You will find that *uniquity* is listed in the OED as meaning the same as *uniqueness*, and to have been around since the 18th century.  I like to think *uniquity* has certain contrasts with *ubiquity*, stretching matters though that may be.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, noticed the similarity to *ubiquity,* but also the resemblance to a malapropism for *iniquity.* Glad this caught your attention.

Comment: @tchrist It's also in [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uniquity). Makes me think of [Uniqua](http://backyardigans.wikia.com/wiki/Uniqua).

Comment: @tchrist Yeah I like that. Presuming that, in enough people's minds, it suggests, and stands in contrast to, ubiquity - then it seems like a cool word to have in the repertoire.

Answer (score 7):

We should not have a [uniquity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uniquity). I'm looking at the current questions tagged with it and am not seeing anything useful in grouping those questions together. Of the current 7 questions:

- 5 questions are asking for a word that means something similar to "unique"
- 1 question is asking about words that have unique meanings
- 1 question seems completely unrelated

Questions about words that *mean* X should not be placed in [x](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x). This leaves [Is there a term for words that have a single meaning or are only used in a single context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10614/is-there-a-term-for-words-that-have-a-single-meaning-or-are-only-used-in-a-singl) as the only relevant question and a tag with only one question in it is kind of useless.

I vote we remove the tag entirely.

Comment: It looks like tchrist tagged all of the posts very recently; hopefully he can drop in and explain the tag.

Answer (score 0):

it could be incorrect to consider the word Uniquity to be redundant/obsolete as it's usage is not unlike well versed.
uniquity is more the disposition of "uniqueness" than "uniqueness" itself; it is also the "degree" or "grade" of "uniqueness." moreover, it is the set of properties purported by "uniqueness."
last but not least, it is the "quality" of "uniqueness."

Comment: I don't think you can have a quality of uniqueness as 'one of a kind' cannot have a modifier. Something can't be more 'one of a kind' than another.

Comment: Hmm. I would agree that in an abstract sense one thing cannot be more 'one of a kind' than another thing. However, in a concrete, real-world sense, I don't believe that uniqueness (or uniquity) is binary. Most objects are composed of many characteristics that are evaluated in many contexts, so you might say that "Lady Gaga is a more unique performer than Brittany Spears." This is an opinion, but it is still a valid use of the adjective.

Comment: In the case of an algorithm that enumerates guaranteed-unique possibilities, would it be reasonable to refer to its disposition-for-uniqueness?